# Is this "dirispit" homebrew race balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, homebrew-review

Me and my friend made a race called Dirispits. Their backstory is that they're intellect spirits given physical form from high intellect/magic areas. These are the bonuses we gave them:

They are medium sized and reach adulthood a few minutes from birth. They tend to live very long lives.

they can speak common, but are very good at learning new languages

Intelligence +2

Wisdom +1

Dexterity +1

Strength -1

They have mage hand and mage proficiency.

They have a special skill called "Intellect Sign" which lets them perfectly analyze an object, area, or person near them. Analyzing an area is basically really good perception, analyzing a person gives them some idea of their motives and abilities, and analyzing an object gives them information on what the object does and an idea of how to use it properly.

Is this balanced in DND 5e?

Comment: Does intellect sign have any kind of action economy cost, usage limit, or anything along those lines? Is "very good at learning new languages" intended to have a specific mechanical meaning, or is it just a flavorsome thing to mention?

Comment: We didn't plan it, but I'm assuming it would cost an action

Comment: What is "mage proficiency"? How are they "very good at learning new languages", in rules language? What does Intellect Sign actually do? These questions need to be clarified before anyone can analyze this race. Voting to close until clarified.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because I think we need you to actually specify how these features work, mechanically, as you'd see in an actual race entry, so that we don't have to guess at what they might possibly be like in the scope of analysing it. Once we have something concrete we can assess that, and if we might suggest it should work differently we can say so.

Comment: by mage proficiency, I mean that their best class is a spellcaster thing. Sorry if that's not clear. The good at learning languages is stupid, you're right. Its just a flavor thing

Comment: I'll try to fix it up

Comment: I'm terrible at asking questions

Comment: Don't knock on yourself, @NielIGuess . Asking question on StackExchange is a skill, and not an intuitive skill. It takes time and effort to learn how to do it well. I've found it most useful to write out rules ideas in the same way the books do, then ask about those.

Comment: There's also the problem that me and my friend didn't exactly think through the mechanical effects of Intellect Sign and I'm not good at mechanical dnd stuff. Thats what makes it hard to give you an answer and fix it up.

Comment: Format it like the race entries. Languages should probably be Common & one or two of choice. Cut out the 'mage proficiency'. Intellect Sign sounds like proficiency with Insight, Investigation, and possibly Perception. Intellect Sign may have a special ability similar to dwarven Stonecutting to understand using objects.